# Can we re-route the DAC output to some other Pins other than PA4 and PA5 in STM32?

Tags: stm32

I am working with STM32H743, and I want to use Pin no. 89 as DAC output. Is  there any register setting where I can change PA4 to PG4(89).

I tried replacing PA4 to PG4 in a working example code, but the output still comes on PA4.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which STM32F7 you are using exactly so I could not lock at the Reference Manual, but I guess it is the same as on STM32F4 devices:

The answer is quite simple: 
NO, you could not reroute the DAC pins.

(A look ad a randomly chosen F7 datasheet also shows only one pin for the DACs)
I simply guess it is not possible to route the output signal through a multiplexer without generating to much interference.

Comment: I understood, thanks for your reply. Well mine MCU is STM32H743 and the link to the reference manual is : (for anyone interested to see)
https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/group0/c9/a3/76/fa/55/46/45/fa/DM00314099/files/DM00314099.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00314099.pdf

Comment: It is not the reference manual that is interesting but the datasheet. If you look at the ST homepage for the STM32H743 you could see that there are ~12 different STM32H743xx (the two letters describe the memory size and the package).
And especially for the pin routing the package is very important :)
In the datasheets you will find some tables for each pin and each peripheral and where the could be routed.

Answer (score 2):

According to the H753 datasheet (can't find a specific one for H743), there are two DAC channels, PA4 is DAC1_OUT1 and PA5 is DAC1_OUT2. It does not appear to be changeable.